# How is USB-C w thunderbolt / docks on ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: usb, dock, usb-c

I just purchased the Dell XPS 9570 and I managed to successfully install Ubuntu on it. However, I have a question about USB-C w thunderbolt because I never used it.

My current set up at work (Asus vivobook R542U) has a VGA, and HDMI port, and I use both ports to hook up my two monitors. I also have a little USB receiver to connect my wireless mouse/keyboard.

Ideally, I would like some sort of dock so I can plug in both monitors in addition to the USB receiver for the mouse and keyboard. That way in the morning and afternoon I just have one thing to plug/unplug, if i can also charge through the USB-c that would even be better so I can leave my charger at home. I know that there are lots of docks that can do this on windows but saw a lot of posts saying that it doesn't work on Ubuntu and I'm confused by all the "noise".

I don't want to buy an expensive dock if it won't work. At the bare minimum, I just need to be able to plug in my second monitor with a dongle.

Does anyone have any experience with this, any recommendations?

Comment: This is asking a too broad and primarily opinion based question (seeking for discussion about experiences to provide recommendations for hardware), which is better suited to Ubuntu Forums or the Ubuntu sub-Reddit.

Answer (score 1):

I too have a XPS 15.

The Dell TB16 seems to work fine for me, i.e. hdmi, usb and ethernet - it charges as well. I have not seen any issues so far but I have only been using for a week

I do the xrandr scaling for hidpi and it makes it a little more complex to script but it works.

I also got a cheap usb c adapter off of amazon and it works as well.

[https://www.amazon.com/Abonda-Multiport-Converter-Charging-Chromebook/dp/B07JG39HGV/ref=sr_1_8?ie=UTF8&qid=1542361893&sr=8-8&keywords=abonda](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07JG39HGV)

Charging works but I only have a 100 watt usb c. and 87 watt apple usb doesnt provide enough juice. I will write back if there are any issues after a week or more of testing.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I bought a cheap usbc dongle/dock on 11/11 that has all the ports I need, it just doesn't support charging. But with could powermanager and the lid closed I'm getting 11+hours of battery life so I can just charge it at home.